# What's the meaning of ?= in a kernel makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I've started learning about building external Linux kernel modules, and in the documentation examples of kbuild ([here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/)) I've come across the line

```
KDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
```

which is then used in

```
make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD)
```

and sets the directory to the kernel source. Now, what's the meaing of that ?= operator? Google gives me nothing! Is that a conditional assignment? Sort of, "define variable as follows unless it already exists in the environment"?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: Have you considered reading the manual?

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference, I didn't realise it was a make-specific operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a makefile, this sets the value of `KDIR` only if it doesn't yet have one.

From the [GNU make documentation on "How to Use Variables"](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html):

> This is called a conditional variable assignment operator